# getFilesDir() vs getDatabasePath()

Tags: android, sqlite, android-context

I am in the process of implementing access to a SQLite database via [SQLCipher](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-for-android/) in my hybrid Cordova app for Android which uses one custom plugin (i.e. written by me).  The SQLCipher documentation - as well as other tutorials on using SQLite in Android - keep referring to `Context.getDatabasePath`.  In my plugin code I store other app files and make extensive use of `Context.getFilesDir`.  In what way is `getDatabasePath` different from `getFilesDir`.  For instance, does it promise a better chance that the database will persist and not somehow get dumped because the OS decides to create "some more room" by deleting some files stored in `Context.getFilesDir`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are resolved to the same directory. `getDatabasePath` calls `getDatabasesDir`.

[getDatabasesDir](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/ContextImpl.java#603):

```
  private File getDatabasesDir() {
        synchronized (mSync) {
            if (mDatabasesDir == null) {
                if ("android".equals(getPackageName())) {
                    mDatabasesDir = new File("/data/system");
                } else {
                    mDatabasesDir = new File(getDataDir(), "databases");
                }
            }
            return ensurePrivateDirExists(mDatabasesDir);
        }
    }
```

[getFilesDir](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/ContextImpl.java#603):

```
  @Override
    public File getFilesDir() {
        synchronized (mSync) {
            if (mFilesDir == null) {
                mFilesDir = new File(getDataDir(), "files");
            }
            return ensurePrivateDirExists(mFilesDir);
        }
    }
```

Notice the returned `File` is resolved by `ensurePrivateDirExists` in both method, which has the same input directory resolved by `getDataDir`.

[getDataDir](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDataDir())

> Returns the absolute path to the directory on the filesystem where all
>   private files belonging to this app are stored.

So, there is **NO difference** in your case.

Do not forget the returned path can change, as the [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDatabasePath(java.lang.String)) says:

> The returned path may change over time if the calling app is moved to
>   an adopted storage device, so only relative paths should be persisted.